# Смещаются главные блоки при уменьшении масштаба

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Помогите, будьте добры, сделать так, чтобы макет не изменялся при уменьшении масштаба

```html
<h1 style="padding-left: 1000px;">Инженерные системы под ключ</h1>

<hr>

<h1 style="padding-left: 1040px;">
  <a href="https://xn----8sbnahitmfedahg7bl.xn--p1ai/?page_id=61">Водоснабжение </a>
  <a href="https://xn----8sbnahitmfedahg7bl.xn--p1ai/?page_id=61">Отопление</a>
  <img class="size-full wp-image-230 alignleft" src="https://xn----8sbnahitmfedahg7bl.xn--p1ai/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/desatascos-tuberias-d03f1f02-e1631822867768.png" alt="" width="600" height="400">
  <img class="size-full wp-image-214 alignleft" src="https://xn----8sbnahitmfedahg7bl.xn--p1ai/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/depositphotos_76853285-stock-photo-floor-heating-system-the-collector-10.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="400">
</h1>
```

Comment: Ты это сделал что бы код красиво выглядел или как ?

Comment: не вижу css для ваших картинок, а `padding-left` можете указать относительными величинами - https://html5book.ru/edinicy-izmereniya-vh-vw-vmin-vmax/ , https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.ru.html